# How to use current timestamp as filename for Hive output

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm using this code to write the results of a Hive query to the specified file:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/user/test.user/test.csv'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ESCAPED BY '"' STORED AS TEXTFILE
SELECT
...
```

I don't want the filename to be `test.csv` however but the unix timestamp, that is `1517213651.csv` or something like that.

I understand I can't use the `concat` function to manipulate the filename, but that is as far as I got.

How do I get the timestamp of the moment of query execution to be the filename of my output?

EDIT: We're using Cloudera.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to put the Hive insert inside of a Shell Script. Define a Date variable in the script and then use the Date Variable to define the output file.

TIMESTAMP_VAR=`date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S"`

FILENAME_VAR=/user/test/${TIMESTAMP_VAR}.csv

You can manipulate the timestamp layout in numerous ways.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add  `TalendDate.getDate("CCYYMMDD")` in file path.

```
"/File1/Output_File_" + TalendDate.getDate("CCYYMMDD") + ".csv"
```

Comment: Sadly we're not using Talend.